# PL/SQL Table type compilation error

Tags: oracle, plsql, types, cursor

I got table types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "TABLE_OF_VARCHAR2" AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "TABLE_OF_NUMBER" AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

And in my package body i got a cursor:

```
cursor c_src_m(trans_list table_of_number, v_codes table_of_varchar2, ...) is
    select ....something
    where ....
    --AND ta.id in (select COLUMN_VALUE from TABLE(trans_list))
    --AND (tb.UNDERLYING_VALUE in (select COLUMN_VALUE from TABLE(v_codes)) OR (v_codes is null or (select count(1) from TABLE(v_codes)) = 0))
```

For each of last 2 lines if i uncomment them i get an error:

> ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
>   *Cause:    attempt to access rows of an item whose type is not known at
>              parse time or that is not of a nested table type
>   *Action:   use CAST to cast the item to a nested table type

I looked over 3 hours for a solution and still couldn't find a working one. Do i really need to cast it as error message says? Does anyone know what is the problem here?

Comment: Cast the variables as their types like `TABLE(CAST(trans_list as TABLE_OF_NUMBER))` and `TABLE(CAST(v_codes as TABLE_OF_VARCHAR2))`.

Comment: Maybe it works if you write your condition as this: `AND ta.id MEMBER OF trans_list
AND (tb.UNDERLYING_VALUE MEMBER OF v_codes OR v_codes IS NULL OR CARDINALITY(v_codes) = 0 )`

Comment: Have you got the same type name declared in your package spec, maybe from an earlier attempt before you created the schema-level types you've shown?

Answer (score 1):

There might be something wrong in your code which you are either not showing in your question or have missed it. Please see the below DEMO which is on the similar lines of your question. I used it the same way you did and its working fine on Oracle11g. Also, you can use `MEMBER OF` as well inplace of your `Select` statement query in where clause. See below and read my inline comments to understand more.

Table and Types Creation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TABLE_OF_VARCHAR2 AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TABLE_OF_NUMBER AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/

Create table Num_varchar(col1 number, col2 varchar2(1000));
/
INSERT ALL 
INTO Num_varchar VALUES (1,'A')
INTO Num_varchar VALUES (2,'B')
INTO Num_varchar VALUES (3,'C')
INTO Num_varchar VALUES (4,'D')
INTO Num_varchar VALUES (5,'E')
SELECT * FROM dual;
/
```

Block:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_src_m(trans_list table_of_number, v_codes table_of_varchar2)
  IS
    SELECT col1,
           col2
    FROM Num_varchar
     --Inplace of select query you can use Member of as well. However if you want to use select query, this will also work. 
    --WHERE col1 IN  (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(trans_list) )
    --AND col2 IN   (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_codes));
    WHERE col1 MEMBER OF trans_list
    and col2 MEMBER OF v_codes;

  --Populated the collection so that i can use it in my query above 
  var_varchr2 TABLE_OF_VARCHAR2:=TABLE_OF_VARCHAR2('A','B','C','D');
  var_number TABLE_OF_NUMBER   :=TABLE_OF_NUMBER(1,2,3,4);
  var1 NUMBER;
  var2 VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN
 OPEN c_src_m ( var_number , var_varchr2);  

    LOOP
      FETCH c_src_m INTO var1,var2;
    EXIT WHEN c_src_m%NOTFOUND;
     --dispalying the result of the cursor
    dbms_output.put_line(var1 || var2);
  END LOOP;
  Close c_src_m;
END;
```

Output:

```
1A
2B
3C
4D
```

Note: If you had create the types in Package specification, it will not work. Until `Oracle11g` , any types created under `PLSQL` scope cannot be referred in SQL statement inside the `PLSQL` block. If you have done so, just create `types` out of package scope and it should work then.